# Swift: match two arrays into one array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have two arrays

```
array1 = ["Fri","Sat","Sun"]
array2 = ["5","6","7"]
```

Now I want to create a newArray: `["Fri5", "Sat6", "Sun7"]`. How to make it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a functional approach, use `zip` and `map`:

```
let array1 = ["Fri","Sat","Sun"]
let array2 = ["5","6","7"]

let result = zip(array1, array2).map { $0 + $1 }
print(result)
```

Output:

> ```
> ["Fri5", "Sat6", "Sun7"]
> ```

`zip` creates a sequence of tuples `[("Fri", "5"), ("Sat", "6"), ("Sun", "7")]` and `map` then creates the final array by taking each tuple and combining the two `String`s into a single `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with this:

```
var array1 = ["Fri","Sat","Sun"]
var array2 = ["5","6","7"]

var array3 = array1.map{ $0 + (array2[array1.indexOf($0)!]) } // ["Fri5", "Sat6", "Sun7"]
```

Answer (score -1):

With Swift 5 you can use one of the five following Playground sample codes in order to solve your problem.

---

## #1. Using [`sequence(state:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2011998-sequence)

```
let array0 = ["Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
let array1 = ["5", "6", "7"]

let unfoldSequence = sequence(state: (array0.makeIterator(), array1.makeIterator()), next: { (iterators) -> String? in
    guard let string0 = iterators.0.next(), let string1 = iterators.1.next() else { return nil }
    return string0 + string1
})

let array = Array(unfoldSequence)
print(array) // prints: ["Fri5", "Sat6", "Sun7"]
```

---

## #2. Using [`zip(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip) and [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/zip2sequence/2905672-map)

```
let array0 = ["Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
let array1 = ["5", "6", "7"]


let array = zip(array0, array1).map({ $0 + $1 })
print(array) // prints: ["Fri5", "Sat6", "Sun7"]
```

---

## #3. Using [`zip(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip) and [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/zip2sequence/3129365-reduce)

```
let array0 = ["Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
let array1 = ["5", "6", "7"]

let array = zip(array0, array1).reduce(into: [String](), { (result, tuple) in
    result.append(tuple.0 + tuple.1)
})
print(array) // prints: ["Fri5", "Sat6", "Sun7"]
```

---

## #4. Using [`AnyIterator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyiterator)

```
let array0 = ["Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
let array1 = ["5", "6", "7"]

var iterator0 = array0.makeIterator()
var iterator1 = array1.makeIterator()

let anyIterator = AnyIterator<String> {
    guard let string0 = iterator0.next(), let string1 = iterator1.next() else { return nil }
    return string0 + string1
}

let array = Array(anyIterator)
print(array) // prints: ["Fri5", "Sat6", "Sun7"]
```

---

## #5. Creating an object that conforms to [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence) and [`IteratorProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol) protocols

```
struct StringArrayConcatenatingSequence: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {

    let firstArray: [String]
    let secondArray: [String]
    private var index = 0

    init(firstArray: [String], secondArray: [String]) {
        self.firstArray = firstArray
        self.secondArray = secondArray
    }

    mutating func next() -> String? {
        guard index < Swift.min(firstArray.count, secondArray.count) else { return nil }
        defer { index += 1 }
        return firstArray[index] + secondArray[index]
    }

}

let array0 = ["Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
let array1 = ["5", "6", "7"]

let sequence = StringArrayConcatenatingSequence(firstArray: array0, secondArray: array1)
let array = Array(sequence)
print(array) // prints: ["Fri5", "Sat6", "Sun7"]
```